# No value in FHIR extensions

Tags: hl7-fhir

I have a C# REST API that uses the Hl7.Fhir.R4 library (3.7.0) with a POST method that receives an object of type *Hl7.Fhir.Model.Patient*:

```
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    [HttpPost()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Patient patient)
    {
        IActionResult status = NotFound();                      
        ...                                                        
    }
```

The Patient object has a list of extensions:

```
"extension": [
    {
        "url": "http://example.com/fhir/extension/patient/origin",
        "valueString": "test"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://example.com/fhir/extension/patient/domainId",
        "valueInt" : "10"
    }...
```

When receiving the JSON as a parameter in the POST function, all the fields have a better value than those of type '*Hl7.Fhir.Model.DataType*':

```
Extension[0]
Children:       {Hl7.Fhir.Model.Extension.<get_Children>d__17}
ElementId:      null
NamedChildren:  {Hl7.Fhir.Model.Extension.<get_NamedChildren>d__19}
Extension:      Count = 0
TypeName:       "Extension"
Url:            "http://example.com/fhir/extension/patient/origin"
Value:          null
```

Am I missing some decorator or attribute or simply can't the object be directly deserialized?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the FhirJsonParser from the library to parse the data? You cannot use a regular JSON parser, because it will not be able to handle the FHIR model correctly.

ETA:
As you now mention in your question, the object cannot be directly deserialized, see first part of my response.

Maybe you can take a look at this project to see how it's done there: https://github.com/brianpos/fhir-net-web-api